# Inserting data using Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, insert

I have a linq query to insert data in table. but its not working. I saw some example on internet tried to do like that but doesn't seems to work.

Tablename: login has 3 columns userid, username and password. I set userid as autoincrementing in database. So I have to insert only username and password everytime.Here's my code.

```
linq_testDataContext db = new linq_testDataContext();
login insert = new login();
            insert.username = userNameString;
            insert.Password = pwdString;
            db.logins.Attach(insert);// tried to use Add but my intellisence is not showing me Add.I saw attach but dosent seems to work.
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: it says "primary key not found" but i have declared primary key in my database i.e. userid which is auto incrementing

Comment: You need to set that primary key field on your DBML as well

Comment: @Nate I set the primary key in DBML also.. but now it throws another exception that goes to linq_test.designer.cs saying "Incorrect AutoSync specification for member 'userid'"
Thanks

Comment: @Ani You should have AutoSync set to OnInsert. Also, you should have the Auto Generated Value property set to True

Comment: @Nate yes sir both AutoSync and Auto Generated are set as u mentioned but now the problem is "I dont have any exceptions or error but data is also not inserted into database." What I should do.

Comment: @Ani, The Add and Remove methods have been renamed to InsertOnSubmit and DeleteOnSubmit

Comment: More technical "elegance" from MicroSlop. Still, an informative discussion, so thanks to the users here.

Answer (score 5):

have a look on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQToSQLBaseCRUDClass.aspx

```
    linq_testDataContext db = new linq_testDataContext();
login insert = new login();
            insert.username = userNameString;
            insert.Password = pwdString;
            db.logins. InsertOnSubmit(insert);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

If you Attach - It should attach to the particular object Context .But it wont reflect in database .If you want to insert any values try with [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx)(object) and do 
[SubmitChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) to save it in database

Comment: @anish Thanx, its throwing another exception that goes to linq_test.designer.cs saying"Incorrect AutoSync specification for member 'userid'" , before that I change my dbml to set userid as primary key.
Thanks

Comment: try to build the dbml and try ..
If you build the dbml only it will create the class.Otherwise also it will throw error ...

Comment: @ Anish Yes I just tried re building dbml. and now its does not throw any exception or error but data is also not inserted in tabel.
Thanks
Aniruddh

Comment: login insert = new login();
                insert.userid = 2;
                insert.username = userNameString;
                insert.Password = pwdString;
                db.logins.InsertOnSubmit(insert);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                label1.Text = "Sucessfull";

This is wht I am trying to do. Last line sets label1 to sucssfull. So when code is sucessfull text prperty of label1 changes to "secssfull" but data not inserted in table

Answer (score 3):

Attach() is the wrong method, you need to call InsertOnSubmit() to let Linq-To-Sql generate an insert statement for you. Attach() is for distributed scenarios, where your entity has not been retrieved via the same data-context that is used for submitting changes.

```
linq_testDataContext db = new linq_testDataContext();
login insert = new login();
            insert.username = userNameString;
            insert.Password = pwdString;
            db.logins.InsertOnSubmit(insert);// tried to use Add but my intellisence is not showing me Add.I saw attach but dosent seems to work.
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for helping but I tried doin it throws an exception saying "no primary key found" but I have userid (autoincrementing) as primary key in my database.

Comment: I recreated dbml, now its not throwing any error but data is also not inserted into table.

Answer (score 3):

Method to save employee details into Database.

[Insert, Update & Delete in LINQ C#](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/LINQ/Select-Insert-Update-Delete-in-LINQ.aspx?Id=95)

```
        Employee objEmp = new Employee();
        // fields to be insert
        objEmp.EmployeeName = "John";
        objEmp.EmployeeAge = 21;
        objEmp.EmployeeDesc = "Designer";
        objEmp.EmployeeAddress = "Northampton";                
        objDataContext.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(objEmp);
        // executes the commands to implement the changes to the database
        objDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```